# ImportError when importing Linestring from shapely.geometry

Tags: python, shapely, linestring, importerror

With this code I tried to `import shapely.geometry`:

```py
import shapely as shp
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Linestring
```

However, I faced the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'Linestring' from 'shapely.geometry'
> (d:\python_work\vritualtest\venv1\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry_*init*_.py)

Comment: Is is  **LineString** and not Linestring -> `from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString`

Comment: Python is case-sensitive. If you are told a name does not exist, check the reference documentation for the proper spelling.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned by @gene, the error is caused by improper import of the [`LineString(coordinates)`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#LineString) class.

You can by means of [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) return a list of valid attributes for `shapely.geometry` object.

```py
import shapely.geometry as geom

print(dir(geom))
```

results in:

```
['CAP_STYLE', 'GeometryCollection', 'JOIN_STYLE', 'LineString', 'LinearRing', 'MultiLineString', 'MultiPoint', 'MultiPolygon', 'Point', 'Polygon', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'asLineString', 'asLinearRing', 'asMultiLineString', 'asMultiPoint', 'asMultiPolygon', 'asPoint', 'asPolygon', 'asShape', 'base', 'box', 'collection', 'geo', 'linestring', 'mapping', 'multilinestring', 'multipoint', 'multipolygon', 'point', 'polygon', 'proxy', 'shape', 'shapely']
```

Alternatively using the

```py
import shapely.geometry as geom

print(geom.__all__)
```

you can get a list of all methods of that module:

```
['box', 'shape', 'asShape', 'Point', 'asPoint', 'LineString', 'asLineString', 'Polygon', 'asPolygon', 'MultiPoint', 'asMultiPoint', 'MultiLineString', 'asMultiLineString', 'MultiPolygon', 'asMultiPolygon', 'GeometryCollection', 'mapping', 'LinearRing', 'asLinearRing', 'CAP_STYLE', 'JOIN_STYLE']
```

A `__all__ = ['LineString']` variable in [the module's source code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/462de3aa7a8bbd80408762a2d5aaf84b04476e4d/shapely/geometry/linestring.py#L10), which basically is a list of strings that defines those symbols that are imported when a program does

Moreover you can check [the source code](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/main/shapely/geometry/linestring.py) where you find the `LineString(BaseGeometry)` class.

Last but not least check [the example](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code/linestring.py), where the the `LineString()` class was called as:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
from shapely.geometry import LineString
...
```

It is also a common Python issue, more information can be found here: [ImportError: Cannot import name X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252543/importerror-cannot-import-name-x).